# How to replace a label in gridview by textbox when i click on edit button added manually in gridview?

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I have a requirement to replace a label in gridview when I click on the Edit button added manually in grid view.

Please see below the code:

```
protected void btnchange_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Button btn = (Button)sender;
    GridViewRow gvr = (GridViewRow)btn.NamingContainer;
    int getindex = gvr.RowIndex;
    gvorderdetail.Rows[getindex].Cells[3].Style.Value = "red";
    gvorderdetail.Rows[getindex].Cells[0].Attributes["style"] = "background-color:Red";
    gvorderdetail.Rows[getindex].Cells[1].Attributes["style"] = "background-color:Red";
    gvorderdetail.Rows[getindex].Cells[2].Attributes["style"] = "background-color:Red";
    TextBox tbx = (TextBox)gvorderdetail.Rows[getindex].FindControl("txtitemqty");
}


protected void gvorderdetail_RowCommand(object sender, GridViewCommandEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.CommandName == "change")
    {
        TextBox tbx = (TextBox)gvorderdetail.Rows[0].FindControl("txtitemqty");
    }
}
```

Can anyone help?

> '>
>            
>            
>                '>

Comment: I don't understand. Why do you want to replace? What's wrong if you tried something? Please, give us some details.

Comment: Why don't you use the edittemplate or gridview or look here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1193585/edittemplate-property-of-aspgridview-control

Comment: Which label you want to replace?

Comment: @shreyas:i want to replace lblqty with the textbox

Comment: It doesnt replace the label by textbox.